# How to make People Picker column Read only in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to make people picker column in my list edit form "Read-only". I found many solutions that worked on SharePoint 2010 but couldn't find a reliable solution for SharePoint 2013/Office 365.

It would be great if someone can point me to a good solution.

Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just gave an answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/47257/why-does-the-readonlyfield-hide-the-field-in-forms/146648#146648), but i suppose it will work here too.

To make People picker readonly, you can use the below JQuery code:

```
$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
$(".sp-peoplepicker-editorInput").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
```

You can also apply them with the help of css:

```
<style>

.sp-peoplepicker-delImage{

display:none;

}
.sp-peoplepicker-editorInput{

display:none;

}

</style>
```

This is the easiest and fastest way to make people picker fields read only in SharePoint

2013/online, but it will make every people picker field on the form read only. So please let me know if you want for a specific column.

Comment: How can we disable specific people picker field in SharePoint Online new form ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same - now does not work for Online, 2018 April

Answer (score 6):

Using `display:none` makes the form look weird and isn't the right approach, it could still be modified. I would actually use the disabled attribute to disable the fields:

```
$(".sp-peoplepicker-editorInput").attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
```

This way it still looks the same and is disabled.

Comment: I guess, you are right but I liked the no Jquery solution, where only CSS worked. I applied it and the form was perfect no weirdness. Thanks for your help and time. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
$(".sp-peoplepicker-editorInput").attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
```

This works for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following to deactiveate a people picker field (and make it actually look "deactivated" as well)...

```
$(this).find('.sp-peoplepicker-editorInput').prop("readonly", true);
$(this).find('.sp-peoplepicker-editorInput').prop("disabled", true);
$(this).find('.ms-entity-resolved').attr('style', 'cursor: text;');
$(this).find('.sp-peoplepicker-autoFillContainer').parent().attr('style', 'color:#b1b1b1;');
$(this).find('.sp-peoplepicker-delImage').each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});
$(this).prop("readonly", true);
$(this).prop("disabled", true);
```

*$(this) is the topelevel div of the field (class is "sp-peoplepicker-topLevel") *

Answer (score 0):

The approved answer and the other CSS tricks didn't worked for me (in custom edit form).

I was able to achieve this by removing the table tbody which contains the people picker control and writing the user name into the table. *( I just wanted to make the first people picker in the custom edit form as read only. That's why index 0 )*

```
$("table[id$='UserField_OuterTable'] tbody")[0].remove();
var markup = $("input[id$='HiddenEntityDisplayText']")[0].value;
$("table[id$='UserField_OuterTable']")[0].append(markup);
```

In **default edit form** , need to put the code (approved answer) inside

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function (){});
```

ie,

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('clientpeoplepicker.js', 'SPClientPeoplePicker', function ()
    {
       $("[class='sp-peoplepicker-delImage']").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
       $("[class='sp-peoplepicker-editorInput']").css({ 'display' : 'none'});  
});
```

Answer (score -2):

try following it worked for me:

```
$('div[title="People Picker"]').attr("contenteditable", false);
```