# SP2013 disable people picker and date field

Tags: 2013, people-picker

What is the easiest way to disable the people picker in SharePoint 2013 - without resorting to editing the display template in SharePoint designer?

I have tried several JQuery approaches but none of them seem to work.

I have tried the solution suggested here: [How to make People Picker column Read only in SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/146685/how-to-make-people-picker-column-read-only-in-sharepoint-2013)

And while it does work in IE it doesn't seem to work in Chrome, on top of that the delete "X" on the people field pop up if I simply hit F5 in IE.

MY current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("select[title='Indholdstype']").closest("tr").hide();
    //$(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").css({ 'display' : 'none'});
    $(".sp-peoplepicker-delImage").prop("onclick", null); 
    $(".ms-dtinput").prop("onclick", null); 
    $(".sp-peoplepicker-editorInput").attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
    $(".sp-peoplepicker-topLevel").attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
    $(".ms-input").attr('disabled' , 'disabled');
});
```

Any suggestions?

Edit: 
This is the HTML:

```
<tr>
        <td width="113" class="ms-formlabel" nowrap="true" valign="top"><h3 class="ms-standardheader">
        <nobr>Byttes med<span title="Dette felt er obligatorisk." class="ms-accentText"> *</span></nobr>
    </h3></td>
        <td width="350" class="ms-formbody" valign="top">
        <!-- FieldName="Byttes med"
             FieldInternalName="ByttesMed"
             FieldType="SPFieldUser"
          -->
            <div dir="none"><div title="Byttes med" class="sp-peoplepicker-topLevel" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker" SPClientPeoplePicker="true"><input name="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_HiddenInput" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_HiddenInput" type="hidden" value='[{"Key":"i:0#.w|nchost\\ncmkl","DisplayText":"Morten","IsResolved":true,"Description":"i:0#.w|nchost\\ncmkl","EntityType":"","EntityGroupName":"","HierarchyIdentifier":null,"EntityData":{"Email":"mkl@nordiccomputer.dk","SPUserID":"2","AccountName":"i:0#.w|nchost\\ncmkl","PrincipalType":"User"},"MultipleMatches":[],"ProviderName":"","ProviderDisplayName":"","Resolved":true}]'><div class="sp-peoplepicker-autoFillContainer" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_AutoFillDiv" style="left: -1px; top: 26px;" InputElementId="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput"></div><span class="sp-peoplepicker-initialHelpText ms-helperText" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_InitialHelpText" style="display: none;">Angiv et navn eller en mailadresse...</span><img class="sp-peoplepicker-waitImg" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_WaitImage" alt="Denne animation angiver, at handlingen er i gang. Klik for at fjerne det animerede billede." src="/_layouts/15/images/gears_anv4.gif?rev=23"><span class="sp-peoplepicker-resolveList" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_ResolvedList"><span class="sp-peoplepicker-userSpan" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.w|nchost\ncmkl_ProcessedUser0" sid="i:0#.w|nchost\ncmkl" resolveduser="true" data-sp-peoplepickerprocesseduser="true"><span class="sp-peoplepicker-userPresence" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.w|nchost\ncmkl_ProcessedUser0_PresenceContainer"></span><span title="Morten" class="ms-entity-resolved" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.w|nchost\ncmkl_ProcessedUser0_UserDisplay" style="max-width: 331px;">Morten</span><a title="Fjerne person eller gruppe Morten" class="sp-peoplepicker-delImage" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_i:0#.w|nchost\ncmkl_ProcessedUser0_DeleteUserLink" onkeydown="SPClientPeoplePickerProcessedUser.HandleDeleteProcessedUserKey(event); return true;" onclick="SPClientPeoplePickerProcessedUser.DeleteProcessedUser(this.parentNode); return false;" href="#">x</a></span></span><input title="Byttes med" class="sp-peoplepicker-editorInput" id="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_EditorInput" type="text" size="1" value="" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" data-sp-peoplePickerEditor="true" AutoFillContainerId="ByttesMed_90904416-c085-4723-82c0-1ca1890faf54_$ClientPeoplePicker_AutoFillDiv"></div></div>



        </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you need to disable 1 people picker on your page or all people picker controls on the page?

Comment: In this particular instance there's only one people picker - so either would do :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could just render them as display fields using CSR:

[Examples from code.msdn.microsoft.com](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sample-8-List-add-and-edit-d228b751)

For User and Date fields it will look something like this, but read the article from msdn:

```
var prepareUserFieldValue = function (ctx) {
    var item = ctx['CurrentItem'];
    var userField = item[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    var fieldValue = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < userField.length; i++) {
        fieldValue += userField[i].EntityData.SPUserID + SPClientTemplates.Utility.UserLookupDelimitString + userField[i].DisplayText;

        if ((i + 1) != userField.length) {
            fieldValue += SPClientTemplates.Utility.UserLookupDelimitString
        }
    }

    ctx["CurrentFieldValue"] = fieldValue;
}

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

  Templates: {
       Fields: {
           "UserFieldInternalName": {
               EditForm: function(ctx) {
                   repareUserFieldValue(ctx);
                   return SPFieldUser_Display(ctx);
               },
               NewForm: function(ctx) {
                   repareUserFieldValue(ctx);
                   return SPFieldUser_Display(ctx);
               }                   
           },
           "DateFieldInternalName": {
               EditForm: function(ctx) {
                    return SPFieldDateTime_Display(ctx);
               },
               NewForm: function(ctx) {
                 return SPFieldDateTime_Display(ctx);  
               }
           }
       }
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - however it seems a little more complicated than I'm looking for. I wouldn't know where to start or end with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable people picker control via below code:

```
var inputuserfield = $("div[title='People Picker']"); 
var checkNamesImage = $("a[title='Check Names']");  
$(document).ready(function () { 
    inputuserfield.attr("contentEditable", false);
    checkNamesImage.hide();
}
```

This will disable all people picker controls on your page.

Comment: Thanks but the doesn't seem to work for me? Should I use it exactly like you have written it - or does it containt placeholders?

Comment: You can use as is. If doesn't work, can you place HTML code part of the control

Comment: I have pasted the HTML of the row in the table that holds the people picker into my original question.

Comment: sorry, my code wont work on this. It works well in SP 2010